# Audit Table Trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle12c

Trying to create a trigger for populating an audit table with old data before changes are made to the base table BOOKS

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER populate_audit_table
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF cost, retail OR DELETE
ON books
REFERENCING NEW as new OLD as old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    dml_operation varchar2(1) :=
CASE WHEN UPDATING THEN 'U'
     WHEN DELETING THEN 'D' 
     ELSE 'I'
END;
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO cost_retail_history
        (isbn
        ,title
        ,pubid
        ,pubdate
        ,cost
        ,retail
        ,discount
        ,category
        ,dml_operation)
        SELECT
            (old.isbn
            ,old.title
            ,old.pubid
            ,old.pubdate
            ,old.cost
            ,old.retail
            ,old.discount
            ,old.category
            ,new.dml_operation)
            FROM BOOKS;
    end;
```

I get the following errors:

> Errors: TRIGGER POPULATE_AUDIT_TABLE

> Line/Col: 8/7 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

> Line/Col: 20/13 PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I also tried using VALUES on the INSERT INTO and not designating a source table ("FROM BOOKS")

```
....VALUES
            (old.isbn
            ,old.title
            ,old.pubid
            ,old.pubdate
            ,old.cost
            ,old.retail
            ,old.discount
            ,old.category
            ,new.dml_operation);
    end;
```

And I get the following errors:

> Line/Col: 8/7 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

> Line/Col: 27/18 PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

I've read and re-read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A64702_01/doc/server.805/a58225/ch4a.htm#1997457 so I feel like I'm missing something simple and just need a point in the right direction.

Thanks,

EDIT:
I dropped the dml_operation as this wasn't required and followed the advice below, but I am still getting errors:

Current version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cost_retail_history 
BEFORE INSERT 
OR UPDATE OF cost, retail 
OR DELETE 
ON books 
REFERENCING NEW as new OLD as old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  CASE 
    WHEN INSERTING THEN 
        INSERT INTO cost_retail_history
        (isbn
        ,title
        ,pubid
        ,pubdate
        ,cost
        ,retail
        ,discount
        ,category)
        VALUES
        (:new.isbn
        ,:new.title
        ,:new.pubid
        ,:new.pubdate
        ,:new.cost
        ,:new.retail
        ,:new.discount
        ,:new.category)
    WHEN UPDATING cost, retail OR DELETING THEN 
        INSERT INTO cost_retail_history
        (isbn
        ,title
        ,pubid
        ,pubdate
        ,cost
        ,retail
        ,discount
        ,category)
        VALUES
        (:old.isbn
        ,:old.title
        ,:old.pubid
        ,:old.pubdate
        ,:old.cost
        ,:old.retail
        ,:old.discount
        ,:old.category);
  END CASE;
END;
```

I'm getting the errors:

> Errors: TRIGGER COST_RETAIL_HISTORY

> Line/Col: 4/9 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

> Line/Col: 22/5 PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I can't tell exactly what line the error is on as this would indicate it's with:

> ...OR DELETE

and

> ... ,:new.title

which does not make sense to me.

Comment: I followed Alex Poole's advice but I'm still not there. Thanks for the answer though, it clarified where my reference was going awry.

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover the new errors and explain the line numbering in the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing `insert ... select ...` then you should not have the parentheses around the column list; i.e.:

```
      INSERT INTO cost_retail_history
        (isbn
        ...
        ,dml_operation)
        SELECT
            old.isbn
            ...
            ,new.dml_operation
            FROM BOOKS;
```

but you should not be selecting from the table the trigger is against - partly because you'll get a mutating table error, and you are attempting to insert an audit row for *every* row in the base table; but mostly because you already have all of the information you need.

With the `values` clase you need to prefix the old/new values with a colon:

```
....VALUES
            (:old.isbn
            ,:old.title
            ,:old.pubid
            ,:old.pubdate
            ,:old.cost
            ,:old.retail
            ,:old.discount
            ,:old.category
            ,:new.dml_operation);
    end;
```

[Read more in the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E)

Oracle has built-in audit tools but presumably this is an exercise.

> I can't tell exactly what line the error is on as this would indicate...

This can be slightly confusing with triggers as they are a mix of SQL and PL/SQL. Because you are getting PL/SQL errors the line numbering starts from the beginning of the PL/SQL part, so here `BEGIN` is line 1, `INSERT` is line 4; `WHEN UPDATING...` is line 22.

Those new errors are just because you don't have a semicolon at the end of the first `INSERT` statement:

```
        ,:new.discount
        ,:new.category);
-----------------------^
    WHEN UPDATING cost, retail OR DELETING THEN 
        INSERT INTO cost_retail_history
```

The error is reported against line 22 because that `WHEN` is where it's expecting to see the semicolon, and the first point it can see the previous SQL command hasn't been completed. The error against line 4 is saying where that not-ended command started; so you're getting two messages for one actual problem.